# How can I run two(take from config) futures concurrently

Tags: scala

I have list of futures:

```
val futures = List(Future(1), Future(2), Future(3), Future(4), Future(5))
```

how can I run only two (value takes from config), not all in parallel?

Comment: A `Future` starts running on creation (provided there's an available thread in the tread pool). By the time your `List` is created, some of the futures might have already completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Futures require an `ExecutionContext` to run - basically a thread pool. If that pool has only `n` threads in it, then that is the amount of parallelism you'll get.

```
val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads)
implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(pool)
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution, I will run only 2 futures in one time

```
def doSome(num:Int) = Future {
    num
  }

  def doSomeS(list:List[Int]): Future[List[Int]] = {
    Future.traverse(list)(doSome)
  }

  def serialiseFutures[A, B](l: List[A], size:Int)(function: List[A] ⇒ Future[List[B]])
                            (implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[List[B]] =
    l.grouped(size).foldLeft(Future(List.empty[B])) {
      (previousFuture: Future[List[B]], next: List[A]) =>
        for {
          previousResults: List[B] <- previousFuture
          next<- function(next)
        } yield previousResults ++ next
    }

  val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

  serialiseFutures(list, 2)(doSomeS)
```

Comment: No. You're _launching_ the the futures 2 at a time. After they've been started they are all _running_ in parallel (as much as the Execution Context will allow), which is precisely what you said you _didn't_ want.